# How can I make this SELECT CASE run faster?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can anyone help me to modify the sql below to make it run faster? Thanks.

```
SELECT DISTINCT B.CLT_NBR ,
       CASE 
          WHEN B.CLT_NBR IN (SELECT CLT_NBR FROM A) THEN 'YES' 
          ELSE 'NO' 
       END AS CHECK  
FROM B
```

Comment: Do a LEFT JOIN instead.

Comment: Is there an Index on CLT_NBR for each table?

Answer (score 2):

Use left join instead of a subquery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT B.CLT_NBR ,
       CASE 
          WHEN A.Id IS NOT NULL THEN 'YES' 
          ELSE 'NO' 
       END AS CHECK  
FROM B
LEFT JOIN A ON(B.CLT_NBR = A.CLT_NBR)
```

**Note:** instead of the A.Id I've used you need to use A's primary key.

Comment: Why not just use `A.CLT_NBR` ? And the yes and no need to be replaced:)

Comment: ... or use IS NOT NULL instead of IS NULL... Thanks for the catch. as to your question, just a personal preference.